# Parse data to two separate lists with condition in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, listview, dart

```
[
    {
        "name": "ITEM-1",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-2",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-3",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-4",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-5",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-6",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    }
]
```

[image]

How to implement this model in futter? I want to show the two lists as shown in and data from JSON above.
The condition for LIST-A is "listNo"="0" and for LIST-B is "listNo"="1".

Comment: So is the input a JSON String or a list of maps? And do you want the output to be two JSON strings or two lists with maps?

Comment: Input is Json string including whole data as shown above, I want output of two lists as shown. The condition for LIST-A is "listNo"="0" and for LIST-B is "listNo"="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it but I think the most easiest to understand solution would be to do the following:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const input = '''
[
    {
        "name": "ITEM-1",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-2",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-3",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"0"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-4",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-5",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    },
    {
        "name": "ITEM-6",
        "desc": "DESCRIPTION",
        "listNo" :"1"
    }
]
''';

  final list1 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
  final list2 = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

  for (final map in json.decode(input)) {
    if (map['listNo'] == '0') {
      list1.add(map as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } else {
      list2.add(map as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }
  }

  print(list1);
  // [{name: ITEM-1, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 0}, {name: ITEM-2, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 0}, {name: ITEM-3, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 0}]

  print(list2);
  // [{name: ITEM-4, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 1}, {name: ITEM-5, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 1}, {name: ITEM-6, desc: DESCRIPTION, listNo: 1}]
}
```

Alternative you could also do the following if you think that looks more clear:

```
  final parsedJson = json.decode(input) as List<dynamic>;
  final list1 = [
    ...parsedJson
        .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
        .where((map) => map['listNo'] == '0')
  ];
  final list2 = [
    ...parsedJson
        .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
        .where((map) => map['listNo'] == '1')
  ];
```